# Term when you make a positive prediction

Tags: probability, confusion-matrix

I see that there are a lot of terms associated with confusion matrices, but I don't see one that involves the ratio of positive predictions to the population i.e. (true positive + false positive) / total population. Does anyone know of such a term? When dealing with cybersecurity, I'm guessing someone could call this the alert rate.

I've looked at articles like this [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_predictive_values) but haven't found anything.

Comment: Why did anyone mark this as unclear? He wants a term for (TP + FP)/total.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of such a term. I'd simply call this the "positive rate" or "rate of positives". [The Wikipedia article on sensitivity and specificity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity) offers a lot of related terms.